# Ошибка при сворачивании

Tags: java, android, исключения

При сворачивании приложения (например при нажатии кнопки home) выходит сообщение "В приложении "narrator" произошла ошибка". Как исправить?

Вот код

```
package com.example.narrator;

import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;
import com.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu;
import com.slidingmenu.lib.app.SlidingFragmentActivity;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class MainActivity extends SlidingFragmentActivity {

    private Fragment mContent;
    VideoView vv;
    SlidingMenu sm;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setTitle(R.string.app_name);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        vv = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);

        vv.setMediaController(new MediaController(vv.getContext()));
        vv.requestFocus();

        setBehindContentView(R.layout.menu_frame);
        getSlidingMenu().setSlidingEnabled(true);
        getSlidingMenu().setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.menu_frame, new time())
        .commit();

        sm = getSlidingMenu();

        sm.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
        sm.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
        sm.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
        sm.setBehindScrollScale(0f);
        sm.setFadeDegree(0.25f);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            toggle();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, "mContent", mContent);
    }

    public void switchContent(String path) {
        vv.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
        toggle();
    }
}
```

Comment: Показать код. Возможно в Вашем `onPause` есть проблема. Или к примеру в `onSaveInstance`.

Comment: Логи в студию! Совершенно очевидно что ошибка в одном из 3-х методов: `onPause()`, `onStop()` или `onDestroy()` - осталось только понять в каком.

Answer (score 3):

mContent = null, потому и ошибка... замени на getContext()